# How to escape a TeX command inside a Verbatim environment?

Tags: fancyvrb

I'm trying this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\fvset{commandchars=\|}
\begin{document}
\begin{Verbatim}
Hello, |\textbf{world}|!
\end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```

However, I'm getting this:

```
! Improper alphabetic constant.
<to be read again>
                   \relax
l.5 \begin{Verbatim}
```

I need to have an ability to place any TeX syntax inside the `|...|` escape. What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key `commandchars` requires three tokens as value; the first one denotes the escape character, the other two the open and close argument delimiters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\fvset{commandchars=\|\{\}}

\begin{document}

\begin{Verbatim}
Hello, |textit{world}!
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```

Note that you don't use `|` before and after, but it replaces the backslash.

[image]

As far as I know, there is no `escapeinside` feature in `fancyvrb` or `fvextra`.